# Not executing the if part

Tags: android

I am validating my server result in my android app.This is my code:

```
if (status.getCode() != -101) {
    if(StringData.equals("correct")){
        myAwesomeTextview.setText("ghdhgjk");
    } else {
        myAwesomeTextview.setText("hjfgfghhhhhhhh");
    }
} else {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(event_1.this,"Please   Check Your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

From server if i am entering correct combination it is giving me reply as "correct".

But in my android app code,it is always going in else part.

Comment: try **equalsIgnoreCase** instead of **equals**

Comment: There is not enough information, please give a [mcve].

Comment: Try using debugger :)

Comment: Like if in login form i entered correct userName and Pasword,it should go to the next page,otherwise it should show  Incorrect Combination.Now for validate this i am calling my service in which if i entered correct information it is giving reply as "correct".So here in my app i am storing service result in StringData and comparing it.But it is always going in else part.

Comment: clean your project once, i have also faced it lol, its weird though

Comment: got the answer....